# Multiple data financial APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yahoo-api

I'm building a Rails app where I want to download historical financial data. I've found this URL that I can use:

[Yahoo Finance API - historical](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=WU&a=01&b=01&c=2014&d=12&e=05&f=2014&g=d)

but I haven't found any way to download multiple financial data simultaneously. The only thing that I have found is to download multiple quotes, like so:

[Yahoo Finance API - quotes](http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL%20CAT%20GOOG&f=nsab)

Is there a way to download multiple historical data simultaneously?

(The reason why I ask is because I want to upload the data to a SQLite database and use that in my app. Of course I can download the data individually, stock by stock, but it would be quite tedious.

Now, I've found this Ruby script on the [internet](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/sp500-code/):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'sqlite3'

START_DATE=['01','01','2014']
END_DATE=['01','05','2014']

YURL="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=#{START_DATE[0]}&b=#{START_DATE[1]}&c=#{START_DATE[2]}&d=#{END_DATE[0]}&e=#{END_DATE[1]}&f=#{END_DATE[2]}&g=d&ignore=.csv&s="
DBNAME = "data-hold/sp500-data.sqlite"
DB = SQLite3::Database.new( DBNAME )


SUBDIR = 'data-hold/yahoo-data'
Dir.mkdir(SUBDIR) unless File.exists?SUBDIR

DB.execute("SELECT DISTINCT ticker_symbol from companies").each do |sym|
  fname = "#{SUBDIR}/#{sym}.csv"
  unless File.exists?fname
    puts fname
    d = open("#{YURL}#{sym}")
    File.open(fname, 'w') do |ofile|
      ofile.write(d.read)
      sleep(1.5 + rand)
    end
  end  
end
```

but when I run it Rails throws me an error:

bad URI (is not URI?):

So my question is basically: What is the best way to solve the problem?)

Comment: `bad URI (is not URI?): ...` what is the bad URI? It is supposed to indicate the problematic URI after this

Comment: Read about threads or Hydra gem.

Comment: Sorry about that. The URI is the one in the script: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=#01&b=#01&c=#2014&d=#05&e=#01&f=#2014&g=d&ignore=.csv&s=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most financial data providers limit historical downloads to one ticker per API call. You can imagine that pulling multiple time series in the same JSON output is confusing and puts heavy loads on servers.

There is a Ruby wrapper of [Intrinio's](http://intrinio.com) API on github, [you can see it here](https://github.com/DannyBen/intrinio), that will make it easier to get historical time series data.

This will pull Apple's price history:

```
curl "https://api.intrinio.com/prices?ticker=AAPL" -u "APIusername:APIpassword"
```

This will pull the current price dimensionally, for up to 150 stocks:

```
curl "https://api.intrinio.com/data_point?ticker=AAPL,MSFT,T,XOM&item=last_price" -u "APIusername:APIpassword"
```

You will, of course, need to exchange your own API keys in the curl, but using the github wrapper will make it easy. API username and password are free.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo historical data does not support downloading more than one symbol at a time. Each URL is unique per symbol.

With yahoo limitations, I would not recommend downloading using more than a single thread.

Comment: Yes, I got around the problem by iterating over hashes in ruby but thanks anyway!